# What's the difference setting Embed Interop Types true and false in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, when adding one reference to the project, the properties window has an option `Embed Inteop Types`, should we set it to `True` or `False`? What's the difference?

Since we have a lot of projects, among some of them, reference was set to `False`, others were set to `True`, it is totally mess up. And the bulid server also have the same warnings:

> [What does “reference was created to embedded interop assembly” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156488/what-does-reference-was-created-to-embedded-interop-assembly-mean)

So we plan to change all the `Embed Inteop Types` to `False`, what risk would we get?

Comment: Never do this, it is a very awesome feature that solves irksome deployment details.  You have to understand COM to truly grok what this is all about.

Comment: @HansPassant, are you saying never set them `false` or never change them (e.g. if they default to `false` already)?

Comment: He plans to set it to False.  Never do this.

Comment: @HansPassant how comes you use irksome and grok. it's very brittish :D

Comment: @Mafii I thought grok was from Stranger in a Strange Land (which is American). Doesn't mean the British might not use it more, of course!

Comment: Grok was indeed invented by Heinlein but it was quite common in the 80s and 90s for UK techs\programmers to use it.

Comment: @HansPassant can you expand on why he should never do this? Can you explain or suggest resources so that we can 'truly grok what this is all about'?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This option was introduced in order to remove the need to deploy very large PIAs (Primary Interop Assemblies) for interop.

It simply embeds the managed bridging code used that allows you to talk to unmanaged assemblies, but instead of embedding it all it only creates the stuff you actually use in code.

Read more in Scott Hanselman's blog post about it and other VS improvements here: [CLR and DLR and BCL, oh my! - Whirlwind Tour around .NET 4 (and Visual Studio 2010) Beta 1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CLRAndDLRAndBCLOhMyWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx).

As for whether it is advised or not, I'm not sure as I don't need to use this feature. A quick web search yields a few leads:

- [Check your Embed Interop Types flag when doing Visual Studio extensibility work](https://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/check-your-embed-interop-types-flag-when-doing-visual-studio-extensibility-work)
- [The Pain of deploying Primary Interop Assemblies](https://blogs.iis.net/samng/the-pain-of-deploying-primary-interop-assemblies)

The only risk of turning them all to false is more deployment concerns with PIA files and a larger deployment if some of those files are large.

Comment: Note that there is a rather significant difference that may break existing code when turning *Embed Interop Types* off. The difference is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects): *“C# 4, and later versions, converts the returned Object to dynamic automatically if the assembly is referenced by the /link compiler option or, equivalently, if the Excel Embed Interop Types property is set to true. True is the default value for this property.”*

Comment: Embedded interop assemblies gave me trouble in a plug-in-based system, in which both the host and the plugins depended on the same *COM*-object. Another problem was merging such assemblies with *ILMerge*.

Answer (score 9):

I noticed that when it's set to false, I'm able to see the value of an item using the debugger.
When it was set to true, I was getting an error -       item.FullName.GetValue  The embedded interop type 'FullName' does not contain a definition for 'QBFC11Lib.IItemInventoryRet' since it was not used in the compiled assembly. Consider casting to object or changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property to true.