# Lync SDK 2013 File not found exception in Skype for Business 2016

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am totally new to the Lync SDK. I took some "getting started" information from here

https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/08/microsoft-lync-desktop-development-how-to-get-started/

After creating a new windows forms project I executed this code on my form

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();
        Console.WriteLine(client.State);
    }
}
```

I logged into my Skype Desktop Application before running the code and got this error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly
>   "Microsoft.Office.Uc, Version=15.0.4603.1000, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=token" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified."

What do I have to fix here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already added the reference to Microsoft.Office.Uc, select it in Solution Explorer, and in the properties window ensure Embed Interop Types is set to "False"

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind providing a small explanation?

Comment: I'd love to, but I have no idea why the reference requires this! it's a fairly complex subject, some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514240/whats-the-difference-setting-embed-interop-types-true-and-false-in-visual-studi