# Type.GetTypeFromProgID() returns null, but New-Object works in Powershell

Tags: c#, com, windows-update

I'm trying to create an instance of the COM object `Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate` in C#. This works in PowerShell:

```
$AutoUpdates = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate"
```

However, this doesn't work in C#:

```
var autoUpdateClass = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Auto­Update");
// var autoup = Activator.CreateInstance(autoUpdateClass) as IAutomaticUpdates;
```

In this case, `autoUpdateClass` is null. Is there any way to activate an instance of this class? Maybe I have to manually specify the DLL, or ensure the correct bitness of my process?

A working alternative would be to add a reference to `WUApiLib.dll`, and setting "Embed Interop Types" to false.  Then I can just do `new AutoUpdateClass()`. The drawback is that I then have an additional `Interop.WUApiLib.dll`, and also people recommend to ["never do this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514240/whats-the-difference-setting-embed-interop-types-true-and-false-in-visual-studi#comment30673821_20514240). Any way, I'd like to know why `GetTypeFromProgID` fails here.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a change. I also tried to set target platform to x64 or x86, which didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a special unicode character between "Auto" and "Update" that you probably don't have in your powershell script, if you paste your code into notepad it will display this:

[image]

PS: more and more people have these kind of hidden char issues these days, not sure why...

Comment: Thanks, incredible that you noticed this! I copy-pasted the string from a blog post on purpose because my first try had a different error and I wanted to avoid a typo. Guess that was a mistake...

Comment: There is actually a VS extension to highlight these kind of problems: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaneRay.InvisibleCharacterVisualizer

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have an Exception. Check with the following code:

```
try
{
    var autoUpdateClass = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Auto­Update", true);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //check if any exception occured
}
```

Comment: hint: this should be a (very valid) comment, not an answer