# where is the Embed Interop Property in VS?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, worksheet

[image]I just can't find the property, but I need the code to work without casting[image]

Comment: What error is it giving you? It seems like that should work. Could you give more context to your code? How are you initializing "workSheet"?

Comment: There is not an error, I just don`t wanna cast all the time, so I read it should be the embed interop property set as true so the compiler will cast it itself, but I can`t find where it`s located.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you are saying. I saw the red underlined "Autofit" and thought there was an error. See my answer and let me know if it works as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The EmbedInteropTypes property can be found for each project Reference as follows:

1. In Solution Explorer go to your project -> References
2. Right click the desired Reference -> Properties
3. Adjust the "Embed Interop Types" property as desired.

I am not sure this will actually fix your problem. The property is set to true by default for any Microsoft.Office.Interop references. Also I have seen some people with very high reputation recommending against doing this. See the following link: [What's the difference setting Embed Interop Types true and false in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514240/whats-the-difference-setting-embed-interop-types-true-and-false-in-visual-studi)

If C# is requiring explicit casts, it could also be that you are using an older version of C#. See the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects) where the following is mentioned:

> Earlier versions of C# require explicit casting for these operations because `ExcelApp.Columns[1]` returns an Object, and AutoFit is an Excel Range method. The following lines show the casting.

Comment: I don't have references, it's dependencies. There are nuget packages, and no properties but "name" and "path", so I thought it`s located in another place, I use vs 2022, c# 10, dot.net 6, maybe this is another problem here, but thank you anyway, your answer can be useful for others)

Comment: Ah, your project type must be different than mine. Under "Dependencies" do you have a "COM" section? If not, are you using a Nuget package for this Excel stuff or are you using the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library? Cause if I create a .NET standard project I have dependencies instead of references. However, I can go to COM -> right click Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core -> Properties -> Change Embed Interop Types as desired